# MUP Deploy Stuck

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, mup

I am trying to deploy my meteor project at AWS(EC2 instance type => t2.micro) using MUP. But somehow it always stucks when it comes to **mup deploy=>Building for web.browser.legacy** and every time I need to restart instance from aws console as it hangs.

I thought it may be the issue of space but result of df -h is

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            481M     0  481M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M  840K   98M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       30G  5.8G   24G  20% /
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/495
/dev/loop1       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/930
/dev/loop2       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5742
/dev/loop3       17M   17M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/784
/dev/loop5       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/5897
/dev/loop4       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6034
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
```

docker container mongodb is also running,

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  
CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        
NAMES
51398378c446        mongo:3.6.3         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   42 
minutes ago      Up 2 minutes        127.0.0.1:27017->27017/tcp   
mongodb
```

AWS Ubuntu OS details-

```
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1029-aws x86_64)
```

Also tried to deploy brand new empty default meteor app but still no luck.

My mup.js file

```
module.exports = {
servers: {
one: {
  host: 'X.XX.XX.XXX',
  username: 'ubuntu',
  pem: '~/.ssh/pemfilename.pem'
  }
 },

 app: {
name: 'cool',
path: '~/meteor/my_cool_app',

servers: {
  one: {},
},

buildOptions: {
  serverOnly: true,
},

env: {
  ROOT_URL: 'http://example.com',
  MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/cool',
  PORT: 3003,
},

docker: {
  image: 'abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-base',
},
enableUploadProgressBar: true,
deployCheckWaitTime:60
},

mongo: {
version:'3.6.3',
servers: {
  one: {}
 }
},
};
```

Meteor Version of my app,

```
Meteor 1.8.0.1
```

also tried with 1.7.0.5 by downgrading my new app, re-installed meteor many times, tried removing node_modules and installed again, no luck.

Sorry for such a long post but I want to provide as much as info possible.

**UPDATE:** May be mup deploy not compatible with ubuntu 18.04

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that it's Ubuntu 18.04 that is the problem? You could increase `deployCheckWaitTime` to 120 and see if that helps?

Comment: We have 2 projects running on 18.04, initially it gave me error of container has no ip address. After changing mongo version in mup.js somehow it started working. But in this third project trying to run on another server we are facing this particular issue. I am not sure whether it is something to do with 18.04 that is why wrote may be word

Comment: Some are facing issues deploying on 18.04 https://forums.meteor.com/t/mup-deploy-stuck/47054/2 , let me search more if nothing works then I need to deploy it on new aws ec2 instance with ubuntu 16. In mup documentation it written that "Be running Ubuntu 14 or 16." http://meteor-up.com/getting-started.html also I am going to check whether ram is causing problem.

Comment: Is `buildOptions: { serverOnly: true }` intended? Because from what I understand is that if this is true, there should be no client build anyway.

Comment: Also - does it work if you locally build server-only using `meteor build --server-only` ?